# JQuery/JavaScript calender slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I´m currently programming an Calender and had the idea to design it like a slider.

Something like: http://wisestartupblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/itunes-cover-flow1.png

The selected day should be centered on the viewport and should show below later on different events.

I´ve created a flex-box and created for each day a rounded div-container and set the parent container to overflow for hiding the non relevant days.

HTML with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="top_container">
    <div id="date_rotation">
    </div>
    </section>
    <nav id="menu_bar">
    </nav>
    <section id="event_container">
      jj
    </section>
    <script>

      // Variables

      var date = new Date();
      var daynames = ["Sonntag","Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Samstag"]
      var monthnames = ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","Juli","August","September","Oktober",
          "November","Dezember"];
      var calStart = new Date(2015, 4, 28);
      var selectedYear = calStart.getFullYear();
      var selectedMonth = calStart.getMonth();
      var selectedDay = calStart.getDate();
      var calLength = 2000;

      //Functions

      function daysofMonths(myyear,mymonth) {  
        var monthStart = new Date(myyear, mymonth, 1);
        var monthEnd = new Date(myyear, mymonth + 1, 1);
        var monthLength = (monthEnd - monthStart) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        return monthLength;
        }

      // Creating Calender

          for (var i=0; i <= calLength; i++) {
            currentDate = new Date(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
            if (selectedDay > daysofMonths(selectedYear,selectedMonth)) {
              selectedDay = 1;
              selectedMonth ++;
                if (selectedMonth > 11) {
                  selectedMonth = 0;
                  selectedYear ++;
                }
              $("#date_rotation").append('<div class="date_picker" id="' + selectedDay + selectedMonth + selectedYear + '"><p>' + selectedDay + monthnames[selectedMonth] + '<br>' + daynames[currentDate.getDay()] + ' ' + selectedYear + '</p></div>');
              console.log("First");
            } else {
              $("#date_rotation").append('<div class="date_picker" id="' + selectedDay + selectedMonth + selectedYear + '"><p>' + selectedDay + monthnames[selectedMonth] + '<br>' + daynames[currentDate.getDay()] + ' ' + selectedYear + '</p></div>');
              selectedDay ++;
              console.log("Secound");
            }
          }

      // Rotate Calender

      // Get Position relative to Container

      $(".date_picker").click(function( event ) {
        var thisPos = $(this).position();
        var parentPos = $(this).parent().position();
        var x = thisPos.left - parentPos.left;
        var y = thisPos.top - parentPos.top;
        var width = $("#date_rotation").width();
        $("#menu_bar").text(x + "px, " + y + "px," + width + "px"); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

SCSS

```
#top_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#event_container {
  margin: 0 auto 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#menu_bar {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 302px auto 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
}

#date_rotation {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
  z-index: 101;
}
#date_rotation .date_picker {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 25px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}
#date_rotation .date_picker p {
  line-height: 50px;
}
#date_rotation .date_picker:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
}
```

What I´m trying to archieve is to center the clicked div with the class date_picker and therefore moving the complete parent overflowed container.

I´m totally stuck and don`t know how to exactly move the parent-container till the selected child-item is centered perfectly =/ I`d love to have an animated solution or hints how I can archieve my goal.

Would really appreciate some hints/answers =)

Solution:

```
$(".date_picker").click(function( event ) {
        var thisPos = $(this).position();
        var parentPos = $(this).parent().position();
        var x = thisPos.left - parentPos.left;
        var y = thisPos.top - parentPos.top;
        var width = $("#date_rotation").width();
        $("#menu_bar").text(x + "px, " + y + "px," + width + "px");

        //Center Selected child-items

        var selectedDate = $(document).width() / 2;
        var selectedLeft = $(this).position().left
        console.log(selectedLeft);
        var dateCentering = selectedLeft - selectedDate;
            dateCentering += 150;
        $("#date_rotation").animate({
          'left' : -dateCentering
          });
      });
```

Best regards Cab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can think of is to calculate the left offset of your centered element (l-cen), the left offset of your current one (l-curr) and calculate the difference = l-cen - l-curr; (centered element minus the one you want to go to...so, if it's left you get a positive value, if it's right you get a negative value). Apply difference to a transition on #date_rotation (if it's right, thus a negative value, your div will move left). That should work. You could technically apply the transition on the first datepicker element as well.

Getting the rotation of the elemnts like in the image you offered will be trickier, but based on the same principle.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me the right hint =) Added my solution on the bottom.

Comment: Glad I could help! Let me know when you're done, I'd love to see it in action